# google maps InfoWindow background does not apply to borders

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with my custom infowindow. All i did was setting background to @color/wallet_holo_blue_light. Here is the source code of my xml and java custom window :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light"
>
```

---

```
private Context context;

public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

    View view = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);

    TextView name_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.windowinfo_title);
    TextView adress = view.findViewById(R.id.windowinfo_adress);
    TextView infotext = view.findViewById(R.id.windowinfo_text);

    name_tv.setText(marker.getTitle());

    adress.setText(marker.getSnippet());

    return view;
}
```

And here's what it looks like in maps: [image: infowindow]

I'd like to find a way to also set borders and the little bottom arrow to the same color.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think the problem is that you have used a ConstrainLayout as the base Layout for your view. Try replacing it with a FrameLayout. If it's not that, the problem could be that the InfoWindow adds some native padding around the custom view you provide.

Comment: The constraint layout didn't work... I searched about this potential native padding but didn't find anything...